# Kafka Consumer poll and reconnection

Tags: apache-kafka, long-polling, kafka-consumer-api

We just started using Kafka for our project. We are using kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0. I have some queries related to KafkaConsumer.

1) I started Kafka Consumer before starting Zookeeper and Kafka server, but still my KafkaConsumer client was able to connect. I have following lines of code

```
    Consumer<String, String> consumer =  new KafkaConsumer<String,String>(props);
    consumer.subscribe(getConsumerRegisteredTopics());
    while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records){
           processRecord (record)
        }
   }
```

2) I read, Zookeeper keeps tracks of active Consumer by the use of poll(long timeout) method call. If i use Long.MAX_VALUE has timeout in poll(), how will zookeeper keeps track of my consumer. Could you please help me understand the behavior of KafkaConsumer poll call.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) if you did'nt start zookeeper and kafka before starting your consumer it can't connect but will try to read metadata from kafka. my experience is that the KafkaConsumer 'poll' call will block undefinetly until it was able to connect and read metadata. in other words ... your consumer did'nt actually connected but is waiting for the kafka cluster to appear.

2) the poll timeout tells the consumer how long to wait until it can return any data. you have to make sure that after poll returns you invoke poll again soon enough for your consumer to stay active. The timeout given to the poll call is not related to the keepalive mechanism of the KafkaConsumer (this is controlled by the ***session.timeout.ms*** property of the consumer properties for your consumer).

Comment: Thanks for your response. If my consumer is waiting for Long.MAX_VALUE in poll method, how will it send heartbeat and how will Kafka server/ Zookeeper knows that my consumer is still alive.

Comment: the heartbeat is there to make sure your application code is alive. so as long as long as the flow of control in your program is inside the poll method you don't have to bother about heartbeats.